# I am unable to make my ball jump in unity 3d using space key

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my ball jump in 3d ball runner game with the space key but after everything despite my code having no errors the ball is not jumping..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jm7Q.png)

can anyone help to find any other ways or find anything wrong in my current code??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, try to paste your code as "code" instead of an image. Your balljump vector is `[0, 0, 0]` and your jumpSpeed is `0` - what would you expect that to do?

Answer (score 3):

replace "balljump" with Vector3.up and set jumpspeed to a high value.

Comment: note: see [answer], which recommends to avoid answering close-worthy questions.